# Migrate site to Amazon cloud

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services

I have a web site running on ASP.net which is hosted on windows server R2.

Is it possible to migrate it to Amazon clound with out doing any programmming/code level changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you buy and configure an AWS EC2 instance it is just a virtualized version of windows server 2008r2 and it should behave identically. No code changes necessary.

Comment: I work with image manipulation in my website, but I heard we need AWS sdk do all those job..

Comment: You don't *need* to do any custom code to get it working on AWS, but there may be opportunities to change your code to take advantage of other AWS features that you didn't previously use.

Answer (score 0):

AWS does provide a powerful IAAS cloud to move all your infrastructure to cloud and use as it is. Based on my a few years of AWS and cloud experience I observed that AWS may have all the tools and documentation to suffice this and you AWS provides best in class eco system to achieve your goals. 
I will also recommend that instead of going direct to AWS you can try try Ravello systems.

Ravello runs on top of AWS and Google provides easy option to move existing infra to Ravello cloud without making any changes.

e.g. If you have your own data center VMS, you can export your in-premise environment and import to Ravello seamlessly without making any changes to network or other configuration.

This means you just need to export vmdk from your DC and import to Ravello so it will be running on top of EC2 as-is keeping your VMware tools, OS patch levels etc intact.

If you are interested you can refer more about this case at http://www.ravellosystems.com/blog/esxi-vm-to-ec2-vmware-tools/